# Casting Type** to void* and then back to Type*

Tags: c++, casting

I am having issues with casting.

Class A has a public method: `char* m()`

funcA receives a double pointer to type A and casts it to a void pointer. In funcB, I wish to cast it back to type A to I can call the method m(). I've tried the below but failed miserably.

```
void funcA(const A** a) {
    funcB((void*)a)
}

void funcB(void* b) {
    A* a = (A*) b; // 
    printf("M: %s", a->m()); // => crash!
}
```

How can I cast the void pointer back to type A so I can call the method?

Comment: Well, `A*` and `A**` are two different things.

Comment: Is `const **A a` really valid syntax? Shouldn't that be `const A ** a`?

Comment: @rattmuff: How would you call the method from `funcA`?

Comment: @unwind It should, post mistake.

Comment: @pts I don't it is called from a system out of my control. I only control funcB.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, since I am new to this would you care to explain my mistake further and how I could reach my goal?

Comment: @rattmuff your mistake is simply that you're not casting to `void*` and back. You're casting to `void*` and then to a third, completely different type. What your *goal* is, only you can say.

Comment: @jalf thanks, my goal is to call method m :P

Comment: This question is tagged `c++`, but you are using C-style casts. Are you sure this is what you need? In C++, it is good practice to prefer C++ casts (`static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `dynamic_cast`) whenever it is possible to avoid C-style casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
void funcA(const A** a) {
    funcB((void*)*a);   // passing an A* to funcB
}

void funcB(void* b) {
    A* a = (A*) b;
    [...]
}
```

or

```
void funcA(const A** a) {
    funcB((void*)a);    // passing an A** to funcB
}

void funcB(void* b) {
    A* a = *(A**)(b);
    [...]
}
```

Note how the type we use for casting `b` in `funcB` must match the type of what we passed in from `funcA`. This is easy to get wrong, since we throw all the type info away once we cast to `void*`, so the compiler is unable to help us out here.

Also be aware that the way it is written now, we lose the `const` qualifier on the original `a`. This is potentially a bad thing. You might want to cast to a `const A*` in `funcB` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`Type**`  is a pointer to a `Type*`, while `Type*` is a pointer to an object of type `Type`.

So if we assume that `funcA` gets a valid pointer to a pointer to an object of type `A`, you have to first dereference it using the `*` operator.

```
funcB((void*) *a)
```

You must see the `A** a` parameter just as what it really is - a value in memory. This value is an address, more specific the address of a `A*`. So if you dereference a `A**`, you get a `A*`. The value you then have is again an address, but of the object of type `A` itself.

- `A**` holds an address to a `A*`
- `A*` holds an address to an object of type `A`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parameter `a` in `funcA` is a `A**`, not `A*`. So you start with `A**` and end with `A*`, and addresses have no members.